# Inject python object in child process

Tags: python, python-3.x

Right now I run python scripts like this

```
python prep.py python slave.py
```

**prep.py** script make some preparation(examine env variables, etc.)

```
prep.py
    import sys
    os.system(sys.argv[1:])
```

**slave.py** contains actual working functions.
Is any way to propagate variables (or other python objects) defined in prep.py to slave.py and make them available from global scope of slave.py?
Thanks for reply!

Comment: one way is to provide input to slave.py via stdin. 
But that would require Popen.communicate or something like that, that handles stdin.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you're not importing the functions from `slave.py` into `prep.py` and running them directly?

Comment: Why don't you just create a function in slave.py which contains the code in `prep.py` and call it before the actual working function in `slave.py`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run both python files every time.
I'd recommend learning about python scope `if __name__ == "__main__":` [concept](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html).

You can import prep from slave.pya and then use the functions or variables from prep in slave like this:

```
import prep
print(prep.function())
# or
print(prep.variable)
```

Comment: As i say, functions in prep.py provides requirements(create folders, updates repos, etc), acts as entry point for running python scripts from args and there are many such scripts(like slave.py). Import functions from prep.py to dependent scripts would mean a hude amount of duplication code.